# Can not read umlauts with boost read_json

Tags: c++, json, boost, encoding, mfc

I can't solve my problem with boost::property_tree::read_json. I have MFC project with MBCS encoding(multi byte character set). I'm getting error during reading data with `ä` character. This is my example:

```
namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

pt::ptree rootRequest;

//Save data in property tree
rootRequest.put("test", "Test ä");

//create stringstream
std::stringstream ss;

//Write rootRequest to stringstream
try
{
    pt::write_json(ss, rootRequest);
}
catch (std::exception const &e)
{
    TRACE("Error: [%s]\n", e.what());
}

//Get string from stringstream
std::string strRequest = ss.str();
TRACE("data: [%s]\n", CString(strRequest.c_str()));

//Clear stringstream
ss.str(std::string());

//Sate data to stringstream
ss << strRequest;

//Save string data in ptree value
pt::ptree rootResponse;
try
{
    pt::read_json(ss, rootResponse);   //Here I'm getting error

}
catch (std::exception const &e)
{
    TRACE("Error: [%s]\n", e.what());
}
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
<unspecified file>(2): invalid code sequence
```

Which is the proper way to read data like that? I hope somebody can help me with this. I need to save data in `string` and then read this again to `stringstream`. This part can't be changed.

Comment: Do not use MBCS encoding.  Use UNICODE for new projects, MBCS has been dead since MS changed Windows' native string format to UNICODE.

Comment: I can't. I have maintenance project and encoding can't be changed.

Comment: JSON cannot handle raw MBCS,  You must convert all strings to/from UTF-8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON cannot store MBCS strings.  Meaning one must convert all labels and values to UTF-8 or UTF-16 before saving.

UTF-8 is the usual choice for JSON, not only because that uses less string memory, but also because UTF-8 encoding has 1-to-1 unique glyph encoding, which UTF-16 doesn't.

Here's how you'd convert your strings:

MBCS to Unicode:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

std::wstring MBCS_to_UTF16(LPCSTR sz)
{
    // MBCS to UNICODE
    std::wstring strResult;

    size_t nCharsDone = 0;
    const size_t nMaxsWords = 6 * strlen(sz);

    strResult.resize(nMaxsWords + 1);

    if (S_OK == ::mbstowcs_s(&nCharsDone, &strResult[0], nMaxsWords + 1, sz, nMaxsWords))
        strResult.resize(nCharsDone);
    else
        strResult.clear();
    return strResult;
}
```

UTF16 <-> UTF8:

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

std::string strUTF8 = boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<char>(L"hello"); // 
std::wstring strUTF16 = boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<wchar_t>("hello");
```

UTF16 to MBCS:

```
std::string UTF16_to_MBCS(LPCWSTR wsz)
{
    // MBCS to UNICODE
    std::string strResult;

    size_t nCharsDone = 0;
    const size_t nMaxWords = 2 * wcslen(wsz);

    strResult.resize(nMaxWords + 1);

    if (S_OK == ::wcstombs_s(&nCharsDone, &strResult[0], nMaxWords + 1, wsz, nMaxWords))
        strResult.resize(nCharsDone);
    else
        strResult.clear();
    return strResult;
}
```

Comment: Since C++11, MBCS conversion can be simplified, for MBCS -> UTF-16: `std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>> conv;
std::wstring outputUtf16 = conv.from_bytes( inputMBCS );` and for UTF-16 -> MBCS: `std::string outputMBCS = conv.to_bytes( inputUTF16 );`. For handling conversion error, catch `std::range_error`.